# Proposed tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Until someone has the capability to propose tag synonyms, I suggest we list them here. Over on stackoverflow, some of us began the discussion of the tag synonyms, in addition to the overall tagging scheme. Some of it resulted in a collaboratively edited [document](http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.Bmox%24r6wDu1/latest). It is far from complete, or coherent, but it can also serve as a guide post for the ongoing synonym and tagging question.

---

**Edit by J.M.**: I (or any of the other mods) will be periodically removing synonym proposals that have been settled. Please check and vote for proposed tag synonyms in the appropriate pages.

Comment: Please change the `%24` to a `$` in the URL, then it will work.

Comment: @Szabolcs, it is a $.

Comment: You are right!  But my browser re-writes it into `%24`, and the page won't load when I click it.  I really don't understand what is happening here ... it's not a problem on the piratepad site.

Comment: @Szabolcs, my browser does the same thing.

Comment: The built-in mechanism to propose tag synonyms is now active.

Answer (score 2):

[interface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface) -> [gui-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-construction)

Answer (score 1):

[button](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/button) -> [gui-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-construction)