# Distinction between plot and plotting

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Currently, there are two tags: [plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) and [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) that are being used to cover the same ground. Is there any reason to keep both of them around? Previously, the [consensus](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/52) was that [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) would cover any of the higher level functions like `Plot`, `ListPlot`, etc., but [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) or even [graphics3d](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics3d) would cover the low level stuff.

Comment: One has 11 questions, the other has 1000+ questions. I think the answer is quite obvious...

Comment: [Voted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/plotting/synonyms).  (And frankly, if it doesn't happen on it's own I'll add the synonym with the moderator tools.)

Comment: I always thought they are synonyms..

Comment: @rm-rf obvious and correct are two different things. I just wanted to check that my opinion was correct.

Comment: So *this* is why I got the [Synonymizer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/badges/72/synonymizer?userid=80) badge after all this time.

Comment: @Verbeia just some _subtle_ encouragement to move the process along. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All done. In the future, please use [Proposed tag synonyms](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44) instead for proposing synonyms.